# Can I register to only my posts on Google Groups without having to register to all e-mails sent to a group?

Tags: google-groups

Can I register to only my posts on Google Groups without having to register to all e-mails sent to a group?

Comment: anyone ? It would be a great feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not an official solution I suppose since it uses Google Alerts instead, but it may work provided when people reply via email they leave the original message (I haven't actually tried it, just thinking outside of the box a bit.):

- Figure out what your signature in reply messages looks like.  Typically it's a combination of your Display Name in your profile and the "secure" email address (the first several characters followed by ...@mail.server)
- Go to the "Edit My Membership" for the group.
- Set **How do you want to read this group?** to *No Email*.
- Save settings
- Go back to the "Edit My Membership" for the group.
- Click the "Get email alerts of messages containing specific keywords" link.
- For the search terms, enter in the information from the first step.  It should be something like "First Last email" or "John Smith jsmi"
- Keep the first drop down (Type) set to Discussions
- Configure the rest to your liking
- Click on the *Create Alert* button.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler solution would be to create a gmail filter (if you use gmail, though Outlook should also be able to do this).  The filter would be on messages From: your@email.addr and To thelist@googlegroups.com.  The rest of the messages you can either delete or label, mark read, then archive.

Comment: Uhm, but if I do this I only receive my own posts and not the answers! Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Gmail organizes by thread, not by message.